# Como criar um elemento e depois de alguns segundos definidos removê-lo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso criar um `label` de aviso como este:

```
 <p id="lblAviso">Salvo com sucesso</p>
```

E removê-lo depois de 3 segundos.

Como fazer isso com [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)? Precisa de algum `plugin`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pode usar assim:

```
var aviso = '<p id="lblAviso">Salvo com sucesso</p>';
var destino = $('#destinoAviso');

//codigo que você quer:
destino.append(aviso);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#lblAviso').remove();
},3000);
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/U42an/)

---

**Outro exemplo** usando fade in/out, escondendo o elemento directamente no CSS.

Neste exemplo uso:

- [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) que é usado para executar código dentro da função anónima uma vez, e onde o ultimo parametro é contador (em milisegundos) de tempo para executar o código.
- [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/), um dos métodos do jQuery para inserir conteúdo num dado elemento do DOM.

Você pode também usar uma cadeia jQuery, usando o [**.delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) e chamando a função callback do [**.fadeOut()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) para remover o elemento quando a animação chegar ao fim.

Assim, e fazendo nota ao CSS `#lblAviso {
    display:none;
}`, o código pode ser:

```
$('#lblAviso').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(function () {
    $(this).remove()
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/df45H/1/)

---

**Outro exemplo**, [**usando uma overlay**](http://jsfiddle.net/2NwpF/1/) (sobrecamada).

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado!

Comment: Como alternativa a adicionar e remover o elemento toda vez, sugiro ter o elemento fixo na página e apenas escondê-lo ou mostrá-lo usando `.show` e `.hide` (ou `.toggle(true|false)`).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, tem razão, adicionei mais alternativas.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, adicionei mais alternativas. Aultima com um overlay. Também pode usar .show() / .hide() em vêz de fade in/out.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode, ao invés removê-lo imediatamente da página, escondê-lo de forma animada controlando o tempo de animação:

```js
$lblAviso = $('<p id="lblAviso">Salvo com sucesso</p>'); // cria o elemento
$lblAviso.hide(); // atribui o elemento como escondido (apesar de ainda não estar na página)
$('#conteudo').append($lblAviso); // adiciona o elemento a outro elemento
$lblAviso.fadeIn(); // exibe o elemento com animação de fade (animação rápida)
$lblAviso.fadeOut(3000); // esconde o elmento com animação de fade (a animação dura 3 segundos)
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/YK6yG/1/)

Se achar necessário remover o elemento da página troque a última linha do exemplo por:

```js
$lblAviso.fadeOut(3000, function() {  $lblAviso.remove(); });
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma interessante é exibir o aviso e remover com um *fade out*:

```java
$('<p id="lblAviso">Salvo com sucesso</p>')
  .appendTo('body')
  .delay(1000)
  .fadeTo("slow", 0, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Note que, ao final, o elemento é removido.

Veja o [exemplo funcional no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7zG6/).

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Já existem inúmeras respostas muito boas para lidar com a questão colocada, vou apenas deixar um exemplo diferente e abstracto do elemento alvo, que pode servir para futuros visitantes.</sup>

#### Introdução

Criar uma "mini" extensão de jQuery que permite adicionar legendas de aviso, sucesso, informação ou erro a qualquer elemento na página, permitindo assim reutilizar o mesmo excerto de código em várias situações.

Ver [exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/fpZC5/), com alguma formatação de CSS para demonstração!

#### jQuery

```
;(function ($) {

    $.fn.goLabel = function( options ) {

        var opts = $.extend({
            type: "success",
            message: "guardado com sucesso",
            time: 3000
        }, options );

        var $label = $('<span/>', {"class": "label"}).addClass(opts.type).html(opts.message);

        return this.append($label).find('.label').delay(opts.time).fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

#### Utilização:

A utilização é simples, através de um `id` ou `class`, chamamos o `goLabel()` com as opções pretendidas:

```
// assumindo as opções por defeito
$( "#devicePrice" ).goLabel();

// com personalização das opções
$( "#newsletterStatus" ).goLabel({
    type: "info",
    message: "receber é muito bom",
    time: 3000
});
```